# How to select uppercase words from a column and separate into a new column?

Tags: python, uppercase

I have a dataset of genes and drugs all in 1 column, looks like this:

```
Molecules
3-nitrotyrosine
4-phenylbutyric acid
5-fluorouracil/leucovorin/oxaliplatin
5-hydroxytryptamine
ABCB4
ABCC8
ABCC9
ABCF2
ABHD4
```

The disperasal of genes and drugs in the column is random, so there is no precise partitioning I can do. 
I am looking to remove the genes and put them into a new column, I am wondering if I can use isupper() to select the genes and move them into a new column, although I know this only works with strings. Is there some way to select the rows with uppercase letters to put into a new column? Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
Expected Output:
  Column 1                                Column 2
3-nitrotyrosine                           ABCB4
4-phenylbutyric acid                      ABCC8
5-fluorouracil/leucovorin/oxaliplatin     ABCC9
5-hydroxytryptamine                       ABCF2
```

Comment: Show expected output

Comment: You want to separate these into 'columns' what tabular structure are you using? How are `3-nitrotyrosine` and `ABCB4` related?

Comment: How are the rows supposed to match up? Getting the uppercase words is simple but the logic of the rows being matched is unclear.

Comment: What library are you using for the "dataset"? Please add a tag for it to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read your file in to a list:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f]
```

Strip out all uppercase as so:

```
mols = [x for x in lines if x.upper() != x]
genes = [x for x in lines if x.upper() == x]
```

Result:

```
mols
['3-nitrotyrosine', '4-phenylbutyric acid', 
 '5-fluorouracil/leucovorin/oxaliplatin', '5-hydroxytryptamine']
genes
['ABCB4', 'ABCC8', 'ABCC9', 'ABCF2', 'ABHD4']
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, separating the upper case is simple:

```
df.loc[df['Molecules'].str.isupper()]

  Molecules
5     ABCB4
6     ABCC8
7     ABCC9
8     ABCF2
9     ABHD4

df.loc[df['Molecules'].str.isupper() == False]

                               Molecules
0                        3-nitrotyrosine
1                        4-phenylbutyric
2                                   acid
3  5-fluorouracil/leucovorin/oxaliplatin
4                    5-hydroxytryptamine
```

However how you want to match up the rows are unclear until you are able to provide additional details.